# Error calling getSupportFragmentManager() from a Broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, bottom-sheet, fragmentmanager

I try to call a method that calls getSupportFragmentManager() however i get:

```
IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has not been attached to a host.
```

The broadcast receiver fires and the method which is in the activity which is currently in the UI fires as below but i get the error:

```
BottomSheet bottomSheet = new BottomSheet();
bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "bottomButtons");
```

All i am attempting to do is call the bottomSheet from a service which i have to do via a broadcast receiver as i cant call getSupportFragmentManager from the service! How can i get the sheet to appear, triggered by an event in my service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Call the method which displays my BottomSheet which is situated in the Activity that is currently displayed in the UI from a background service. I used MutableLiveData.

I initialised a global Boolean finished, in my service;

```
public static MutableLiveData<Boolean> finished = new MutableLiveData<Boolean>();
```

When the required event triggers in my Service i set the value of the live data variable to true. with

```
finished.setValue(true);
```

In the activity i need to display the BottomSheet i am observing this variable via:

```
finished.observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>(){

@Override
public void onChanged(Boolean aBoolean){
if(aBoolean){
//I call my Method here which displays my Bottom Sheet, this is the method that contains the getSupportFragmentManager().
}
}
});
```

I hope this can help anyone in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment`s are part of the UI. `BroadcastReceiver` and `Service` are background components and do not have anything to do with UI. You cannot even call the method `getSupportFragmentManager()` from a `BroadcastReceiver`. This shouldn't even compile!

Only `Activity` components can do stuff with the UI.

Comment: Thank you, so how can i from and event that is triggered in my service in anyway call this BottomSheet to be displayed? are we saying this is impossible? is there no strategy to trigger something on the UI from a service?

Comment: I have solved the issue, Using MutableLivedata<Boolean> which i observe in the activity in the UI upon change if the boolean is true i call the method which displays the BottomSheet.